# Center axisLabel in flot

Tags: jquery, css, flot

as shown in the figure below, my yaxis label is shown on the top of the axis not in the center, one part of the label is not shown

[image]

Here the option used:

```
var options = {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    bars:{
        align: "center",
        barWidth: 0.5
    },
    xaxis:{
        axisLabel:"YEARS",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 10,
        ticks: ticks
    },
    yaxis: {
        axisLabel: "Number of publications",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 3,

    },
    legend:{
        noColumns: 0,
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
        position: "nw"
    },
    grid:{
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 2,
        backgroundColor: {colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"]}
    }
  };
```

How can I center the label "Number of publication" in the yaxis?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ Paste your code accordingly in given link

Comment: how to add `jquery.flot.axislabels.js` to jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's an attempt at creating a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GA2sR/  It does not demonstrate your problem, though.  The label is centered fine.

Comment: I just rename my css file and rename it again to his first name and is fixed!!! why this? but thanks for JSFiddle is great tool.